# Jest doesn't update test

Tags: node.js, jestjs

jest for testing my function in function in typescript everthing worked great for days and today I update a function and change the expected value but when i use jest in commande line it still use the old test but if I use the button to run my test field in PHPStorm it worked great.

I precises that I already cleaned jest cache